# How to hanlde fcm push notification when app is killed, without using WakefulBroadcastReceiver as its decprecated in 26.1.0?

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to call some service from my application when application receives a notification when the application is either in the background or is killed.

Earlier, I was using a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` for
handling such notifications, but it is deprecated now.
Can someone please help with it?

Thanks in advance.Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217345/wakefulbroadcastreceiver-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Use JobScheduler

> As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so.) Instead, developers should use **android.app.job.JobScheduler** to schedule a job, and this does not require that the app hold a wake lock while doing so (the system will take care of holding a wake lock for the job).

Answer (score 0):

just create a service extend `FirebaseMessagingService` and override `onMessageReceived`

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
  override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage?.from}")
  }
}
```

add service to your manifest

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

[offical document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vahung3990.I already implemented this.But no help.

Comment: This won't work because onMessageReceived is only called when app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` you should extend regular `BroadcastReceiver`.

Then, in `onReceive` you can enqueue work using `JobIntentService`